# How can I select data by date from a MySQL datetime column using Knex?

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, datetime, knex.js

I want to select a data by the created_at that is a datetime column but I want to select it using only the date

In MySQL you can make it like this:
`` SELECT * FROM table WHERE date(`created_at`) = '2022-08-15 ``

But in Knex I cannot make it work. I saw in their documentation that you can use date(), so I tried like this:

```
function getData(req, res) {
    app.db('table')
        .select(table.*)
        .where(date(created_at), '=', '2022-08-15')
        .then(table => res.json(table))
```

But it returns this message: ReferenceError: date is not defined

However if I just write:

```
.where(created_at, '=', '2022-08-15')
```

It doesn't work because, like I said, created_at is a datetime column, and I only have the date as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to use `whereRaw` for this https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#whereraw

Can either be done using parameter binding like so

```js
function getData(req, res) {
    app.db('table')
        .select(table.*)
        .whereRaw('date(created_at) = ?', ['2022-08-15'])
        .then(table => res.json(table));
```

or if you trust the value and don't need any escaping then you can insert the value directly like so

```js
function getData(req, res) {
    app.db('table')
        .select(table.*)
        .whereRaw('date(created_at) = "2022-08-15"')
        .then(table => res.json(table));
```